# Get minimun value of a column by comparing previous n rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the min value of a column by compare the value in current row with the value in previous 2 rows, I know this can be done by creating 2 columns with the shift(-1) and shift(-2) and return the min value of the row, but I would like to know if there is any way to do it better if I extend the range from previous 2 rows to n rows.

for example in below dataset

```
 df= pd.DataFrame([12,11,4,15,6,],columns=['score'])
>>> df
   score
0     12
1     11
2      4
3     15
4      6
```

create new columns prv_score_1, prv_score_2 for previous value

```
>>> df['prv_score_1'] = df['score'].shift(-1)
>>> df['prv_score_2'] = df['score'].shift(-2)
>>> df
   score  prv_score_1  prv_score_2
0     12         11.0          4.0
1     11          4.0         15.0
2      4         15.0          6.0
3     15          6.0          NaN
4      6          NaN          NaN
```

Create a Minimum column and get the minimum value of the row

```
>>> df['Minimum'] = df.min(1)
>>> df
   score  prv_score_1  prv_score_2  Minimum
0     12         11.0          4.0      4.0
1     11          4.0         15.0      4.0
2      4         15.0          6.0      4.0
3     15          6.0          NaN      6.0
4      6          NaN          NaN      6.0
```

Anyway to do better?

Comment: `df.min(1)`... this? Why did you think the `loc` call was needed?

Comment: In your example you're comparing the score in current row with the scores in the two following ones.

Comment: yes df.min(1) will do, because I was filtering the columns to compare. my question is instead of creating 2 new columns using shift(), is there any way to do it better

Comment: I see. Yes, you need a rolling window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need rolling min with window 3 i.e

```
df['new'] = df['score'][::-1].rolling(3,min_periods=1).min()[::-1]

  score  new
0   12.0  4.0
1   11.0  4.0
2    4.0  4.0
3   15.0  6.0
4    6.0  6.0
```

Comment: Why does this answer have a downvote? It answers the question quite sufficiently.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ as long as the person explains why I don't bother much at them. I made myself give less emotions towards them. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the rolling function:

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

In your case, this will do the trick:

```
df[::-1].rolling(3, min_periods=1).min()[::-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with `rolling.min()`.  For example with window size `2`, use:

```
df.rolling(2).min()
```

Then change `2` to `n` for the more general case.